# Is there an "increment" shortcut in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an easy way to auto increment integer value in a Google Sheet like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Vim?

If not, how do I go about creating such a shortcut?

Comment: Where does `vim` stand for?

Answer (score 4):

Select the cell above (one less than the required value) and drag down (via the [fill handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797395/1505120)) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed.

Works "sideways" as well and up or to the left (normally) decrements by `1`.

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

With the following little piece of code you can increment any number by 1 (or whatever you choose).

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value == "_incr") {
    var v = e.range.offset(-1,0).getValue();
    if(typeof v == "number") {
      e.range.setValue(v+1);
    } 
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The *onEdit* trigger is only executed when the input corresponds to the magic word *_incr*. After that it will check if the value is a number and increment by 1.

### Note

This doesn't provide [data integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_integrity).

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Auto-Increment](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evser7shf-crVMtStuZZeNvJqhw9ulFpcEeQ4sd3ZuA/edit?usp=sharing)**
Add the code in the scipt editor (*Tools > Script editor*) and press the save button and you're on the go !!

Comment: hi, thank you for taking the time to respond,  im not familiar with google sheets function, would you explain how to trigger the function for certain field?

Comment: If you type in <i>_incr</i>, then for every cell the above number is incremented. You can also create a menu item, so that you don't have to type in anything. Do you want to do that?

Comment: i apologize, my description for the problem is uncomplete for who is not familiar with vim, i originally meant for (short) keyboard shortcut to increment in 1 the number assumed to be in the selected field, just like "ctrl+;" set the field to the current date, instead just increment, and again thanks for your time and effort, i dont take that for granted.